# RKPaginator - no result - no error

Tags: objective-c, pagination, restkit

I'm trying to use `RKPaginator` to collect an Array of results from my API.

Here is my code:

```
RKEntityMapping *commentMapping = [APICallComment RKGetCommentMappingForManagedObjectStore:self.appDelegate.managedObjectStore];

NSString * convertedPath = [APICallCommentListCommentsPattern stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@":photoId"withString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",photoId]];

// Register our mappings with the provider
RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:commentMapping
                                                                                            method:RKRequestMethodGET
                                                                                       pathPattern:convertedPath
                                                                                           keyPath:@"comments"
                                                                                       statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];

[self.session.objectManager addResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];
self.session.objectManager.requestSerializationMIMEType = RKMIMETypeJSON;

commentsPaginator = [self.session.objectManager paginatorWithPathPattern:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", convertedPath,@"?per_page=:perPage&page=:currentPage"]];

commentsPaginator.perPage=ListCommentsNumberOfCommentsPerPage;

__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
[commentsPaginator setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(RKPaginator *paginator , NSArray *comments , NSUInteger page) {

      //Code for success
    } failure:^(RKPaginator *paginator, NSError *error) {
      //Code for failure
    }];
```

My problem is that nothing happens. I'm waiting even for an error but I have nothing. My API doesn't receive anything. That means there is a problem during the compression block.

I've added these lines:

```
RKLogConfigureByName("*", RKLogLevelTrace);
RKLogConfigureByName("RestKit*", RKLogLevelTrace);
```

But there is still nothing. No error in both sides.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't called `loadPage:` anywhere, so you haven't asked for any download to happen.

Also, the point of a path pattern is to be a pattern, so you might want to reconsider explicitly adding the id yourself and using that in the response descriptor (hote that I don't know enough to say that what you have is wrong and it could work just fine).

Comment: Completely my mistake. With `loadPage` it's working better... Thank you for your time.